# Extend custom Rails preloader with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I'd like to trigger eager loading on a relation with an `#includes` call, that was modified with a custom preloader using `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` on a Rails 7 app, Ruby 3.2:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  has_many :taxons
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

records = Product.where(id: [1,2,3,4])
scope = Vendor.where.not(id: [5,6])
preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records:, associations: :vendor, scope:).tap(&:call)

puts records.first.association_cached?(:vendor)
=> true

puts records.includes(:taxons).first.association_cached?(:vendor)
=> false
```

I need the `scope:` argument because some users aren't allowed to access certain resources.

Without the `includes(:taxons)` call, the association `:vendor` is correctly eager loaded and cached. But in the second case, it seems like the whole eager loading of `Preloader` is somehow dropped.

Is there a way to include a custom preloader as a chain argument along with other `includes`? I get an error when I try to include the preloader itself like this:

```
records.includes(preloader).to_a
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named '#<ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader:0x00007f573bc31ab0>' was not found on Product; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:302:in `association'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jan Vítek pointed out, any queries called on a relation will reload all objects, and therefore loose all already eager loaded associations.

Due to the structure of the code, I can't guarantee to always call the custom `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader`, so I came up with a little monkey patch for `ActiveRecord::Relation#preload_associations`:

```
raise "ActiveRecord::Relation#preload_associations is no longer available, check patch!" unless ActiveRecord::Relation.method_defined? :preload_associations
raise "ActiveRecord::Relation#preload_associations arity != 1, check patch!" unless ActiveRecord::Relation.instance_method(:preload_associations).arity == 1

module PreloadWithScopePatch
  def preload_with_scope(association, scope)
    scope = model.reflect_on_association(association).klass.where(scope) if scope.is_a?(Hash)
    (@preload_with_scope ||= []).push([association, scope])
    self
  end

  def preload_associations(records)
    super.tap do
      Array(@preload_with_scope).each do |associations, scope|
        ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records:, associations:, scope:).call
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Relation.prepend(PreloadWithScopePatch)
ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class.delegate(:preload_with_scope, to: :all)
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
records = Product.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).preload_with_scope(:vendor, Vendor.where.not(id: [5,6])).includes(:taxons)

records.map { |r| r.association_cached?(:vendor) }
=> [true, true, true, true]

records.map { |r| r.association_cached?(:taxons) }
=> [true, true, true, true]
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` needs the objects to be initialized to fill in the data however calling any queries on `ActiveRecord::Relation` will reload the objects.

You have to call the `Preloader` after calling any reload causing method of `ActiveRecord::Relation` on `records`. It shouldn't have any performance difference from adding the custom preloader to the chain since it still would have to be called each time at the end.

Adding it to the chain would require some monkey patching. The starting point for it would be `ActiveRecord:: Relation#preload_associations` to where you have to pass the scope.

If you just need the data, call `includes` first, then `Preloader`. I you need the data first without `taxons` and later include them, call a second custom preloader to load the `taxons` data. It will also have a positive impact on speed since `products` and `vendors` don't have to be loaded and initialized again.

```rb
records = Product.where(id: [1,2,3,4])
scope = Vendor.where.not(id: [5,6])
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records:, associations: :vendor, scope:).tap(&:call)

# associations filtered by the scope are initialized but return nil, although association_id is present
records.map{|r| r.association_cached?(:vendor)}
=> [true, true, true, true]
records.map{|r| r.association_cached?(:taxons)}
=> [false, false, false, false]

ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records:, associations: :taxons).tap(&:call)

records.map{|r| r.association_cached?(:vendor)}
=> [true, true, true, true]
records.map{|r| r.association_cached?(:taxons)}
=> [true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` is always called before the `include`, due to the structure of the code. So I guess I have to settle with a monkey patch that has not too much impact. Thanks for your answer and pointing me in the right direction where to put the monkey patch :)